# Why does operator () with type argument can be applied to type in the context of result_of?

Tags: c++, decltype, result-of

As fas as I understand, `result_of_t` should be a type, that will be at the end of the evaluation of an expression. `decltype(&foo)` in the code below yields the type `int (*)(int)`, but what does `(int)` outside of `decltype`?

```
#include <type_traits>

int foo(int) {
    return 0xdeadbeef;
}

int main()
{
    using T = std::result_of_t<decltype(&foo)(int)>;
    T t;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but what does (int) outside of decltype?

It confuses us. [`std::result_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of) is defined in a "cute" way. It's specialized for `F(Args...)`. Where `F` is the functor type, while `Args...` are the arguments being fed to it.

In your case,  `(int)` is the arguments to the call.

This, and certain other quirks of the definition, is why `std::result_of` was deprecated in C++17, and replaced with `std::invoke_result`.